# Frame size below navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

From within `rootController` I am manually adding a UITableView, but I don't know how I would get the frame size ...

```
Controller *rootController = [[Controller alloc] init];
UINavigationController *tempNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];
[self setNavController:tempNavController];
[tempNavController release];

[window addSubview:[[self navController] view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I am currently using: `[[[self navigationController] view] frame]` but this does not account for the "navBar" height or that of the "statusBar" (giving me: 480). Is there a way to get the size of the frame below the statusBar / navBar or do I have to subtract 20 + 44 off the number above?

NB: I am using `navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height` to get 44

Comment: Why are you manually setting the frame of your table view at all?  If you just add your table view controller to your navigation controller's viewControllers array, the table should automatically be sized properly for you, with no need for you to set your table view's frame or bounds.

Comment: Yeah, if you add the table and enable it to automatically resize, it should fit by default.

Comment: Its not a UITableViewController, its a UITableView, that I am adding to a UIViewController. I appreciate that I could use a UITableViewController, but I was just looking at trying to do it without one.

Comment: You'll save yourself a lot of headaches by using a UITableViewController instead.  The system is developed assuming you will be using one with the other.

Comment: @Ryan what if one page has two UITableView?

Comment: @Perisheroy: since the notion of child/parent view controllers was introduced, you can use a UITableViewController for each of a scene's UITableView instances.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can try to subtract

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height
```

And

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height
```

From your

```
self.window.frame.size.height
```

Cheers,
Rog

Comment: Is there a way to access the navigation bar if you don't have direct access the `UINavigationController` via `self.navigationController`?

Comment: Have you tried `self.parentViewController.navigationController` ?

Comment: I'm doing this from within a UIView subclass library so I'm not sure if I can access the `self.parentViewController` property. One thing I did find that appears to be working for all cases so far is simply to get the height of the UIViewController via `((UIView*)self.nextResponder).frame.size;` I know it's ugly :|

Answer (score 2):

**safeAreaLayoutGuide**
When the view is visible onscreen, this guide reflects the portion of the view that is not covered by navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars, and other ancestor views. (In tvOS, the safe area reflects the area not covered the screen's bezel.) If the view is not currently installed in a view hierarchy, or is not yet visible onscreen, the layout guide edges are equal to the edges of the view.

So you can use:

```
self.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
```